# Where to add timer in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When I display the page, I need to make requests every one minute to update the data in the table that is presented. I don't know where to add this timer logic, since all controller lifecycle methods should end at the appropriate time - I guess?

Where should I put the timer?

Comment: I guess you have to call & schedule timer from `viewWillAppear:` method & invalidate & set it to nil in `viewWillDisAppear:` method.

Comment: You can start timer in viewWillAppear, but if you want this update to occur while app is not active, you have to use background fetch and you can tell iOS how frequently you want to update, but iOS will dictate when it will allow you to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are saying you need to make request every one minute after you display the page, good solution is to start the timer in `ViewWillAppear()` method and stop it in `ViewWillDisappear()` - it will be running just when the ViewController is visible in foreground. Unbinding the `OnTimedEvent` is important to avoid memory leak.

Is that what you need or do you have some more specific requirement?

Sample code:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    public MyViewController(IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private bool timerEventBinded;

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
         base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
         if (timer == null)
         {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Interval = 60000;
         }

         if (!timerEventBinded)
         {
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            timerEventBinded = true;
         }

         timer.Start();
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        if (timer != null)
        {
           timer.Stop();
           if (timerEventBinded)
           {
              timer.Elapsed -= OnTimedEvent;
              timerEventBinded = false;
           }
           timer = null;
        }

        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object src, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you add some appropriate reasoning as to why this code is what OP is looking for. Just leaving a piece of code and saying "this works for me" isn't a good answer.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Sure, just added.

Comment: @DavidRiha this does not work when the app is in background, and I am sure, user is not expected to keep app open for hours.

Comment: @AkashKava Yes, it does not. Did you read the question? "When I display the page, I need to make requests every one minute to update the data in the table that is presented." It doesn't seem to me that he/she would like to update the table every minute even if the app is in background.